# IntelliJ Plugin Dev - Cannot prepare plugin for deployment

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jbehave, intellij-plugin, jbehave-plugin

I am trying to download the source of an IntelliJ IDEA Plugin (for JBehave integration) from a [github repo](https://github.com/witspirit/IntelliJBehave), and basically build it into a jar, which I can distribute to my team (which they can then drop into their plugin directory for installation).
What I have done so far:

1. configured the IDEA SDK (I downloaded the source for latest version of the community edition and built it)
2. Downloaded the source from the repo via zip, as well as git clone
3. Created the project from scratch, as well as trying to "Import"
4. Ran `mvn install` in the command line, ran "Make Project"
5. Then I looked for the command (according to this [tutorial](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Getting+Started+with+Plugin+Development#GettingStartedwithPluginDevelopment-anchor5)) to

   > Build | Prepare Plugin Module  for Deployment.

[image: Screenshot of me trying to look for the command]

As you can see, the command is not there.

What am I doing wrong?  I have tried fiddling with the project/module settings ad nauseum and I feel like I'm getting nowhere.

Comment: Looks like your are using the plain Java module type, plug-ins should be created using the **IntelliJ Platform Plugin** module.

Comment: How do I configure that?

Comment: Nvm, I figured it out.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like I was using an outdated version of IntelliJ (10.5).  I ran IntelliJ Idea 12, and I created the project IntelliJ Platform Plugin (as @CrazyCoder suggested).  From there I was able to build it.